# LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2008, linker-errors

I Had VS2010 installed but found that intellisense wasn't working.  I looked on the web and found that I wasn't the only one who had that issue.  So, I installed VS2008 and everything was fine.  Then I decided to clean up my computer and removed VS2010 and immediately started getting this error on my programs (new and old).  Even a simple test program that has one cout command.  I tried repairing VS2008 and that didn't work so I tried to uninstall and then reinstall and still I am getting the same problem.

I have looked online for this issue and though I have found a lot of other people are experiencing this issue it is not the same.  They are having problems with other external references, not the ones that should automatically be included like kernel32 and lib32 etc.

I also tried the solution that worked for some people with their other references and I included the path (with and without quotes) to my kernel32 directory but still I get the same problem, or in some instances I will get

LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32.obj'

with and without quotes in the linker config.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the option you are looking for here is -MT instead of -MD.  I ran into the same problem.  You will notice that when you use this option, the size of the DLL is much larger (includes dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

> I included the path (with and without quotes) to my kernel32 directory

It looks like you're pointing to `C:\Windows\System32` which is where the DLL might be, but that's not where the .lib file will be.

In VS 2010 it's probably somewhere like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib
```

I don't have ready access to VS2008 to say where kernel32.lib gets installed by default for that product.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense but I tried that and I get the same error only now it shows LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\windows\v5.0\lib.obj' P.S. I only have up to v6.0A and that one doesn't have a lib directory, only a bin

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody comes up to this again, I found the solution which worked for me.

In my case UAC from Win 7 and / or antivirus sortware was / were denying the access to kernel32.lib. After starting VS 2008 as an Admin and deactivating Virus Scan for the project folders it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and just resolved it. I had the SDK installed, however, the VCVARS32.bat couldn't find the SDK, so it defaulted to paths that didn't exist (where VS2008 is installed). I forced this to work by modifying the VCVARS32.bat ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat", see line 13):



`11: @call :GetWindowsSdkDir

12:

*13: @SET WindowsSdkDir=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\

14:

15: @if not "%WindowsSdkDir%" == "" (`

I had to do it this way as I have VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 installed, as most of us probably do who have to support multiple projects across multiple teams, so updating anything global, like the actual environmental path, could lead to mixing SDK versions.