# fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, libraries

I've been getting this error ever since I installed the .NET Framework SDK for 64-bit programming on my Visual C++ 2010 Express compiler. I can't compile even a simple program at all because of this single error I'm getting. My platform is x86. Here is a snap shot if it helps:

[image]

I don't know what more to say. I just downloaded this compiler yesterday and it was working fine. I wanted to upgrade from 32-bit programming to 64-bit so I could work with Assembly, so I downloaded this [SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx). I searched on Google and even here on Stackoverflow. Google didn't help much, but I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926866/lnk1104-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib/7013508#comment21162060_7013508) that seemed similar to mine but the answers didn't do much justice. Does anyone know why this error is occurring and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: I'd try this: First search your Program Files directory to see where kernel32.lib is installed, then check the Library Directories listed in your project's VC++ Directories property page and verify that the paths are correct.

Comment: This was triggered by path mix-ups between multiple SDK installations for my VS2017 installation. I used the VS2017 installer to remove all Win10 SDKs and Toolsets (140 and 141), updated my installation, then re-installed them via the VS2017 installer. After that, problem solved.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Check the VC++ directories, in VS 2010 these can be found in your project properties. Check whether `$(WindowsSdkDir)\lib` is included in the directories list, if not, manually add it. If you're building for X64 platform, you should select X64 from the “Platform” ComboBox, and make sure that `$(WindowsSdkDir)\lib\x64` is included in the directories list.

Comment: There are a lot of directories. How do I know which one to add it to? For example, there's Executable Directories, Include Directories, etc. [Here's a screen shot](http://gyazo.com/2ee0b79d39dcbfde56d6417a4fc9260b).

Comment: You'll probably need to modify all of them. Bin directory of the sdk goes in the executable directories property, the lib directory goes in the library and so on

Comment: You added them as an environment variable or a full path??? If its the fOrmer, did you check if that variable was recognised by VS

Comment: I simply copy-pasted `$(WindowsSdkDir)\lib` between the semi-colons `;` where I did not see one in the full path.

Comment: Well, you need to check if that variable exists.. Simply from the vc++ directories windows, click on any value box, you'll notice an drop arrow, click that and select edit. From the new dialog that popped up, expand macros and see if $(WindowsSdkDir) exists and make sure that the path it refers to is valid. I not then you can simply replace $(WindowsSdkDir) mentioned in my answer with the full path of the sdk.

Comment: I did that and it says at the bottom: `$(WindowsSdkDir) C:\Program Files\Microscoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\ `

Comment: I rechecked your question, you are building for x64 so you need to add $(WindowsSdkDir)\lib\x64 and \bin\x64 in library and executable directories respectively

Comment: The library already has that, but do I need to just add `\bin\x64` in the Executable one? Where do I add it in?

Comment: Try adding $(WindowsSdkDir)\bin\x64 in executable

Comment: If one directory has `$(WindowsSdkDir)include` in it, does it mean I don't have to put in `$(WindowsSdkDir)\bin\x64` because they are the same thing??

Comment: You don't need to modify the include directories, just the executables.... And yes you still need to add references to the x64 directories each in its respective category

Comment: I just found out this only works when my platform isn't x64. That is, when I change it from x64 to Active(Win32) my compiler is all right. But I still can't compile with 64-bit as I want.

Comment: Thats because you are not linking to the x64 libraries

Comment: Sorry I'm out... Maybe you can try uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK

Comment: New development: It seems I downloaded the SDK for Windows 7, but I'm using Windows *XP*. I'm currently uninstalling the current Windows 7 one and I'm looking for a Windows XP version of the install. Hope I get this one right!

Comment: Unless there's a way to fix this for all future projects created without doing this every time, this answer is more of a hack than an answer.

Answer (score 19):

Change the platform toolset to: "Windows7.1SDK" under project properties->configuration properties->general

Comment: This worked instantaneously for me. I had (over time) installed a few tools, and when I came back to my VC++ project, it would not compile (missing headers) etc. I started to hand code include paths, that worked, then I hit link errors, then I tried this solution, and as I said, it just worked!! Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have in VC++ directories (Right click project, Click Property Page),

- Include Directories: $(IncludePath)
- List item Library Directories: $(LibraryPath)

Answer (score 5):

For command line (i.e. - makefile) users only:

1. When you install VC++ Express, it is 32-bit only. So, things go into *C:\Program Files **(x86)***.
2. Then, you decide to upgrade to 64-bit capabillities. So, you install the SDK. But it is 64-bit capable. So, things go into *C:\Program Files*.

You (like me) probably "tuned" your makefile to #1, above, via something like this:

```
MS_SDK_BASE_DOS := C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A
ENV_SET         := LIB="$(MS_SDK_BASE_DOS)\Lib\x64"
```

But, now, you need to change that tuning to #2, above, like this:

```
MS_SDK_BASE_DOS := C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1
```

(Don't miss the "v7.0A" to "v7.1" change, as well.)

Answer (score 3):

Add lib path of WindowsSdks in project->properties->Configuration Properties->VC++ Directories -> **Library directories**.

I added following path and error goes::

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib;**

My system is **Win-7, 64bit, VS 2013, .net framework 4.5**

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar error, the problem stopped when I checked my "Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies" list in the project properties. I was missing a semi colon  ";" just before "%(AdditionalDependencies)".
I also had the same entry in twice. You should edit this list separately for Debug and Release.

Comment: + vote for reminding me that settings change when switching from debug to release, or Win32 to x64. Bah, this project I'm working on his a lot of pre-reqs set before you can do anything, and I made a bonehead mistake and forgot to switch to the correct configuration before tweaking all the values...

Answer (score 2):

I had a differnt problem on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017 but with the same effects. I think my problems came down to VS being installed onto a drive other than "C:\". I solved the problem by Reinstalling [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk)

First I had to uninstall the Windows SDK (there were two versions installed). Then ran the executable. Once installed, ran visual studio and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I just met and solved this problem by myself. My problem is a little different. I'm using visual studio on Windows 10. When I create the project, the `Target Platform Version` was automatically set to `10.0.15063.0`. But there is no `kernel32.lib` for this version of SDK, neither are other necessary header files and lib files. So I modified the `Target Platform Version` to `8.1`. And it worked.

**Environment**:

- Windows 10
- Visual Studio 2015
- Visual C++

**Solution**:

1. Open the project's `Property Page`;
2. Navigate to `General` page;
3. Modify `Target Platform Version` to the desired target platform (e.g. `8.1`).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

gero's solution worked for me.
In Visual Studios 2012, take the following steps.
 - Go to Solution Explorer
 - Right click on your project
 - Go to Properties
 - Configuration Properties -> General
 - Platform Toolset -> **change to Windows7.1SDK**

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution doesn't work, check to see if you have **$(LibraryPath)** in Properties->VC++ Directories->Library Directories. If you are missing it, try adding it.

Answer (score 0):

OS : Win10, Visual Studio 2015

Solution :
Go to control panel ---> uninstall program ---MSvisual studio ----> change ---->organize = repair

and repair it.
Note that you must connect to internet until repairing finish.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Today in Visual Studio 2017 I had the same problem.

The cause in my case turned out to be a bad environment setting in NETFXSDKDir (`NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1`). It needs to be instead `NETFXSDKDir=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86`. Specifically, as set in this batch file (my directory actually has 4 different files) for the Command Prompt for VS2017:

```
%comspec% /k "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars32.bat"
```

as I am reluctant to change one of the "as installed" batch files… even more as that batch file calls another yet another:

```
@call "%~dp0vcvarsall.bat" x86 %*
```

...instead for my specific C++ command-line app, I simply added the explicit path text: `;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86` for a total string in "Library Directories" like this: `$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.10240.0\um\x86`. (Right click on project, Properties → Configuration Properties → VC++ Directories → Library Directories.) That resolved my "fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'" error. I found that hint in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/506).

Note this is reproducible in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise 2017 Version 15.1 (26403.0) even after successful "repair" install… when creating a new Visual C++ Win32 Console Application and attempting to compile.

In fact, unless a blank application is created, the default template also includes reference to `<SDKDDKVer.h>` and with that I get this additional error: `Error (active)  E1696   cannot open source file "SDKDDKVer.h"`. So I [created an empty C++ project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235629.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

In **Visual Studio 2017**, I went to **Project Properties** -> **Configuration Properties** -> **General**, Selected **All Platforms** *(1)*, then chose the dropdown *(2)* under **Windows SDK Version** and updated from **10.0.14393.0** to one that was installed *(3)*. For me, that was **10.0.15063.0.**

[image]

***Additional details:*** This corrected the error in my case because  **Windows SDK Version** helps VS select the correct paths. **VC++ Directories** -> Library Directories -> **Edit** -> **Macros** -> shows that macro **$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)** has a path with the version number selected above.