# Using pthread in c++ on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, pthreads

I am trying to use the pthread library on windows. I downloaded a zip with a Pre-built.2 folder in it and followed the instruction.

What I have done so far:

- all .h files from `POSIX\Pre-built.2\include`into `MS VS2013\VC\include` folder
- all .dll files from `\dll\x86dll\x86` into `VC\bin`
- all .lib files from `lib\x86`  into `VC\lib`
- In `Property->Config->Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`, `pthreadVC2.lib;pthreadVCE2.lib;pthreadVSE2.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)` // `pthread.lib` already in Inherited values

I included `pthread.h` inside my program and when trying to build solution, the following error appears:

```
Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file 'pthread.lib'
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

EDIT:

The `Include Directories` and `Library Directories` are

```
A:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include;$(IncludePath)
```

and

```
A:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib;$(LibraryPath)
```

respectively now.  But I still get the same error message.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053337/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib) might help

Answer (score 2):

Add the folder *containing* the LIBs to `Configuration Properties -> VC++ Directories -> Library Directories`.