# My C++ project can't find the .exe

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I haven't been coding in some time and I wanted to open up a new project to wipe of the rust.

- I go to File New... Project
- I press on "Visual C++"
- Select an empty project and name it "test"
- In the solution explorer I right click on Source Files
- I select Add New Item...
- I select the C++ file (.cpp) and name it main.cpp (no reason)
- I write this simple piece of code right here:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I go to Build Build Solution (and here start the problems...)
When it builds it shows this Output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
1>Done building project "Test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It also goes to the Error List and shows this error:[LNK1104](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRkqE.png)

I have no idea what's the problem here because this exact same way always worked and now it suddenly doesn't? Can anybody explain me what am I doing here? I searched all over the neat and found people with similar problems but didn't really understand the solutions.

Comment: Looks like you have a broken installation of visual studio.

Comment: Well, I do have an outdated version and there's a new update for it but I think it's hardly the case.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053337/fatal-error-lnk1104-cannot-open-file-kernel32-lib

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/q/15053337/2785528

Comment: Why did you select the empty project template? Doesn't the `Win32 Console Application` template give you what you want?

Comment: No, no it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Try Properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> System -> Set the SubSystem to 'Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)'.
It helped to me.